# How to create Azure Virtual Machine automatically using Power Automate Flow

Tags: azure, power-automate

I have a microsoft power app where you can fill up an information and on-submit data will saved on SharePoint List. Once, data submitted on SharePoint list, Microsoft Power Automate Flow will run.

So, my question is this, Using this data i want to create Azure Virtual Machine Automatically. Is that possible? If so, could you please guide me through this process?

I used "Validate a template deployment" action on the Flow and I used following url for "Template URI" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/master/get-started-with-templates/quickstart-template/azuredeploy.json" and for "Parameters URI" i have used this url "https://github.com/merpssirk/Azure-virtual-machine/blob/main/deploymentParameters.json".

Since i am very new in azure, i do not know whether this is right way to do or not?

Basically, I want create or deploy Virtual Machine Automatically using Power Automate Flow.

Your help is much appreciated.
Many thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Create or update a template deployment` of Azure Resource Manager connector providing the URLs for Template and Parameter files. Below is the flow of my Logic App.

[image]

*RESULTS:*
[image]